# GRANT ROLE inside a trigger?

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-grant

is there a way in Oracle to execute the `GRANT someRole TO someUser;` command inside a trigger?
I tried it, but it does not seem to work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: think of a LOGON trigger.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but perhaps via `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`?

Comment: Yes I have. Doesn't work either :(

Comment: [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:698152300346710865) about this.

Answer (score 0):

Most DDL statements are not allowed in triggers because they force a COMMIT to be executed.  The few exceptions to this rule are only applicable to system event triggers (startup, shutdown, etc) but it doesn't appear this trigger is a system trigger.  Reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_triggers.htm).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use DDL commands within a trigger since a commit a transaction and you don't have a way to rollback a transaction if something goes wrong. If it is very important and you have to do it, then only you should execute DDL commmands within a trigger. Perhaps you could achieve it using an autonomous transaction.

Here is an example =

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
  AFTER INSERT ON my_table
   DECLARE
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT someRole TO someUser';
     COMMIT;
   END;
```

Please let me know if that works for you.

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: Hi Aditya, I think I tried that as as well, but it did not work. The only thing that seems to do the job is th following:

Comment: DBMS_JOB.submit (jobNumber, 'someProcedure');